# CSS3 :checked direct sibling only uses first rule listed

Tags: css, css-selectors

It seems that Chrome (27.0.1453.116) and IE (10.0.9200.16618 w/ update to 10.0.6) both suffer from CSS rule blocking by order listed.

Given the following CSS rules, the first is only applied. If I switch the order, the rendering switches. Likewise, an `!important` will also force the later rule to be applied, but the first is still not applied.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label>div { background-color: #00A; };
input[type="radio"]:checked + label>span { color: #A00; };
```

Here's a MWE on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzBRR/

Any feedback/suggestions (especially regarding Best-Known Methods) or another CSS+HTML only equivalent solution.

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting that bit, using `!important` should not have any effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the stray semicolons at the end of each line. They're not supposed to be there as rulesets aren't semicolon-terminated. Instead, the first trailing semicolon is breaking your second selector.

Simply remove them and it should work:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label>div { background-color: #00A; }
input[type="radio"]:checked + label>span { color: #A00; }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/jzBRR/1)

Comment: Shoot me, please. >.< This is why I don't like switching between JS, C, Assembly, and CSS.